# How to get HtmlTable returned from function to display in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So what I am trying to accomplish is dynamically creating a table based on a List of attachments passed to a function.  If my "Vendor" object has a List of 20 attachments, I have a function that generates a table and loops through the attachments and puts each filename in a new cell and row in the table.  The function that generates the table works fine and populates the table as expected.  However, when the function returns the HtmlTable from the function it only appears on the web page as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable.  How can I get this function to return the table instead of a string literal?

Here is my function in Details.cshtml

```
@model EnterpriseServices.Vendor.Vendor
@using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    int incrementer = 1;
    TagBuilder hrTag = new TagBuilder("hr");
    TagBuilder newLineTag = new TagBuilder("br");
}

@functions {
    public static HtmlTable PopulateTable(IList<EnterpriseServices.Vendor.Attachment> attachments)
    {
        HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

        foreach (var a in attachments)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = Path.GetFileName(a.AttachmentPath);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Here is the section of code that calls the PopulateTable() function in Details.cshtml:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attachments)
</dt>

<dd>
    @PopulateTable(Model.Attachments)
</dd>
```

Here is what is looks like on the web page:
[image]

Comment: You can't use WebForms controls in MVC or Razor.  You should replace that code with simple Razor HTML blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use WebForms controls in MVC or Razor.

Instead, you should replace that code with a [Razor helper](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-7-helpers.html), embedding `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in the loop.

Comment: I am new to working with MVC/Razor.  I do not know what a Razor helper is but I am going to look it up right now.  Thanks.

Comment: This worked.  I changed the function to a Razor helper with embedded <tr> and <td> tags and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks was correct with using the Razor helper.  Here is the Razor helper that worked, the Razor helper is posted for everyone's reference:

```
@helper PopulateTable(IList<EnterpriseServices.Vendor.Attachment> attachments)
{
    <table>
        @foreach (var a in attachments)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="@a.AttachmentPath">@Path.GetFileName(a.AttachmentPath)</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Your `href` is wrong; you can simply write `href="@a.AttachmentPath"` and get rid of the variable.